# Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x

Tags: objective-c

Error log when run the above function:

```
2013-06-28 21:10:32.435 B3 Controller[68665:c07] Logged knob : 1
2013-06-28 21:10:32.436 B3 Controller[68665:c07] -[ViewController rotaryKnobDidChange]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71721f0
2013-06-28 21:10:32.437 B3 Controller[68665:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController rotaryKnobDidChange]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71721f0'
```

Thank's for help me.

This the code :

```
... - (IBAction)rotaryKnobDidChange:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)rotaryKnobDidChange:(RotaryKnob*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Logged knob : %ld",(long)(sender.tag));
    switch(sender.tag)
    {
        case 0:
            self.driveLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", self.DriveKnob.value*100];
            break;
        case 1:
            self.edgeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", self.EdgeKnob.value*100];
            break;
        case 2:
            self.reverbLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", self.ReverbKnob.value*100];
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That usually means there is a datatype mismatch somewhere. You are trying to set a value to an object that isnt the same.

Comment: It looks like to me that you call `rotaryKnobDidChange:` without adding the parameter `sender`. Check all of the places where you call this method and verify you are always passing a sender.

Comment: Duplicate of 500 others (and that's just this week).

Answer (score 2):

According to this error, somebody somewhere is trying to call `[viewController rotaryKnobDidChange]` instead of `[viewController rotaryKnobDidChange:self]`. The colon is part of the name — you can't leave it out — and the argument is not optional.